# Reply to "How are you?" : Are "I'm thirsty" "I'm hungry" "I'm angry" etc. okay?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, answers

When someone asks you "How are you?" the expected or usual reply (I assume) would be "I'm fine" "Not bad" "As usual" etc. Instead, is it okay to give a more specific and honest reply of your current condition i.e. "I'm angry" "I'm hungry" "I'm thirsty",etc. ?

Comment: "How are you?" is largely rhetorical in idiomatic English. Do **not** respond with an honest description of your current condition. Do not respond, for instance: _"I'm relatively well except for my acne and flatulence."_ Instead, respond with the expected _"I'm fine; and you?"_ The sole exception is that, if you and your questioner both speak Yiddish, it is acceptable to respond: _"Don't ask."_

Comment: Context plays a role here. If it's someone you are extremely close to, feel free to reply _I'm angry_, _I'm hungry_ or however else you're feeling. Likewise if the question is coming from someone who genuinely seems to care or who has a responsibility to care (such as a therapist or doctor). But to the cashier at the till, just say _I'm fine_, _I'm good_ or something along that line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine to do in informal situations, such as speaking to a friend, but it sounds a little bit weird and informal in formal situations. The normal

> How are you?
>
> I'm fine(, thank you). / Not bad.

is more of a conversation starter than an actual question, for example it is used in formal settings (e.g. interviews, meetings) to start a more important and serious topic:

> Interviewer: Welcome. How are you today?
>
> Interviewee: I'm fine, thank you.
>
> Interviewer: So, {insert name here}, what are your thoughts on {topic X}?

Saying something that isn't the normal reply in such a place derails the purpose of the "How are you" in that sort of situation, and seems informal and "out-of-touch" if you do say it.

Comment: Well, you can answer, "**I'm feeling hungry/thirsty**" to "**How are you?**" Nobody says you can't.

Comment: @SovereignSun Again, in an informal situation you can obviously say that (e.g. to a close friend or a family member), but not in a formal situation. The use of the phrase “How are you?” is more or less of an “unspoken formality” in English, and not an actual question.